# Java -Ant Integration Problem

Tags: java, ant, sunspot

I have created a Greenhouse Monitoring system using SunSPOTS. The code modules are written in java.
The problem I face is that I need to run these programs using ant commands. Im able to do it through a terminal independently but Im unable to find a way to build a gui and execute these modules through that.

Any kind of help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this links this might help

http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the problem correctly, then what you need is a way to call your ant script from java ui (may be some button or link). You can use Runtime.exec("cmd ant targetname") to call ant script.

Comment: This will work on windows, perhaps @Garima should tell us which platform is working on.

Comment: I used the following code but it gives the error.       Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();   
rt.exec(cmd ant build_new);                                        Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "ant", . 
  expected

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide more details, f.e. what kind of GUI ? Web based, Java Swing, Applet ... ? Note that most IDE's (Eclipse, NetBeans,IntelliJ ..) have ant support, means write and start ant scripts. What platform ? If you need a platform independent mechanism maybe Groovy is for you; so f.e. build your swing gui with [Groovy swingbuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Swing+Builder) and start your ant logic with [Groovy antbuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Ant+Integration+with+Groovy)